# Accesing gmail from bluemix in php imap

Tags: php, email, imap, ibm-cloud

I am trying to get mails from gmail account with php imap in bluemix application.
I believe it is a bluemix config issue.

I have enabled imap in the gmail acount.

In bluemix I added a file .user.ini and I wrote : extension=php_imap.dll

The php code is:

```
<?p

    hp
     set_time_limit(60); 
     /* connect to gmail with your credentials */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';

    $username = 'mygmailaccount@gmail.com';  

    $password = 'mypassword';
    /* try to connect */

    print_r('debug: just before accessing gmail');

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    print_r('debug: i did not die when accesing gmail ');

    /*here is more code but I do not access this...  */

    ?>
```

When I run this code I get the first debug message and that's all. no error or other debug.

I might guess that something with the imap.dll setting is wrong.

Can I have advice on this?
:)

Comment: Your php code is missing in the question.

Comment: As Henkealg said, your code is missing so please edit post so it displays.  Some things you may need to do to get gmail to work is 
make sure your gmail password is a strong 8 character password and not too simple and change your gmail account settings to allow access to less secure apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application root directory create the following directory and file if not present:

```
.bp-config/options.json
```

The `options.json` file should have the following content:

```
{
   "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["imap"]
}
```

Push your application again using:

```
cf push
```

Make sure you have IMAP enabled in your Google account and also turn on access for less secure apps per link below:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

**DISCLAIMER**: Google does not recommend to turn on access for less secure apps.